# Bootstrap Tab view content is not showing

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have implemented tab using bootstrap, there are 4 tabs and each of them has contents in them, but while I am executing the code all the contents of that tab along with all other tabs content are showing under the first tab and the other tabs content are blank.here is the code so far:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active settingshead"><a href="#first" aria-controls="first" role="tab"
                                        data-toggle="tab" value="first">
                                          1
                                        </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#second" class="settingshead" aria-controls="second" role="tab"
                                        data-toggle="tab" value="second">
                                          2
                                        </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#third" aria-controls="third" role="tab"
                                        data-toggle="tab" value="third">
                                          3
                                        </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#fourth" aria-controls="fourth" role="tab"
                                        data-toggle="tab" value="fourth">
                                          4
                                        </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
  </div>

<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="first">
                  <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. Jane Doe</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Physics</p>
          </div>
              </div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="second">
                    <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. Martin</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Chemistry</p>
          </div>
                </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="third">
                      <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. John</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Biology</p>
          </div>
                  </div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="fourth">
                        <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. Watson</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Math</p>
          </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: oh sorry, had some internet issue, now yours one is accepted answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Try This maybe Helpful to you.
>
> Mistake
>
> In your code, you are missing `<div class="tab-content"> </div>` which is main part to target tab content on tab switch event.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<!--script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script-->

<div>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active settingshead"><a href="#first" data-toggle="tab">1</a></li>
    <li class="settingshead"><a href="#second" data-toggle="tab">2</a></li>
    <li class="settingshead"><a href="#third" data-toggle="tab">3</a></li>
    <li class="settingshead"><a href="#fourth" data-toggle="tab">4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="first">
      <div class="namedesig">
        <h4>Dr. Jane Doe</h4>
        <p>PhD in Applied Physics</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="second">
    <div class="namedesig">
      <h4>Dr. Martin</h4>
      <p>PhD in Applied Chemistry</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="third">
    <div class="namedesig">
      <h4>Dr. John</h4>
      <p>PhD in Applied Biology</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="fourth">
    <div class="namedesig">
      <h4>Dr. Watson</h4>
      <p>PhD in Applied Math</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Follow the order

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- Nav tabs -->
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#home" role="tab">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile" role="tab">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#messages" role="tab">Messages</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#settings" role="tab">Settings</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home" role="tabpanel">content 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">content 2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">content 3</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings" role="tabpanel">content 4</div>
</div>
```

Here is a working example http://bootsbin.com/bin/view/47/

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qbz8v88/)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTabs">
        <li role="presentation" class="active settingshead">
            <a href="#first" data-toggle="tab">1</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="settingshead">
            <a href="#second" data-toggle="tab">2</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="settingshead">
            <a href="#third" data-toggle="tab">3</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation" class="settingshead">
            <a href="#fourth" data-toggle="tab">4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="first">
        <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. Jane Doe</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Physics</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="second">
        <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. Martin</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Chemistry</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="third">
        <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. John</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Biology</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="fourth">
        <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. Watson</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Math</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have edited your code.

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li class="active">
   <a data-toggle="tab" href="#first">1</a></li>
         <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#second">2</a></li>
         <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#third">3</a></li>
         <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#fourth">4</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">
         <div id="first" class="tab-pane fade in active">
            
   <div class="namedesig">
      <h4>Dr. Jane Doe</h4>
      <p>PhD in Applied Physics</p>
   </div>
         </div>
         <div id="second" class="tab-pane fade">
            <div class="namedesig">
      <h4>Dr. Martin</h4>
      <p>PhD in Applied Chemistry</p>
   </div>
         </div>
         <div id="third" class="tab-pane fade">
   <div class="namedesig">
      <h4>Dr. John</h4>
      <p>PhD in Applied Biology</p>
   </div>
         </div>
         <div id="fourth" class="tab-pane fade">
   <div class="namedesig">
      <h4>Dr. Watson</h4>
      <p>PhD in Applied Math</p>
   </div>
         </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
         <script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.js" ></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

<div>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
                <li role="presentation" class="active settingshead"><a href="#first" aria-controls="first" role="tab"
                                        data-toggle="tab" value="first">
                                          1
                                        </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#second" class="settingshead" aria-controls="second" role="tab"
                                        data-toggle="tab" value="second">
                                          2
                                        </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#third" aria-controls="third" role="tab"
                                        data-toggle="tab" value="third">
                                          3
                                        </a>
                </li>
                <li role="presentation"><a href="#fourth" aria-controls="fourth" role="tab"
                                        data-toggle="tab" value="fourth">
                                          4
                                        </a>
                </li>

            </ul>
  </div>
<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="first">
                  <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. Jane Doe</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Physics</p>
          </div>
              </div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="second">
                    <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. Martin</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Chemistry</p>
          </div>
                </div>
  <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="third">
                      <div class="namedesig">
            <h4>Dr. John</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Biology</p>
          </div>
                  </div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="fourth">

            <h4>Dr. Watson</h4>
            <p>PhD in Applied Math</p>

                    </div>
     </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try above complete example